Light traveling long distances
I am a high school student and I always wonder if light is an EM wave, then how it can travel such large distances? I tried to search on the internet but the answers have solution of Maxwell's equations which I don't understand completely. Can someone explain in simple terms?

The energy of a photon is related to its frequency which is unchanging (in EM equs), but intensity does decrease as the energy flux decreases with the inverse square law. So the question really how come we can detect light from so far away?

So distance light travels depend upon the intensity of the source

and the medium it is travelling through.

I have one more question can I ask

Aslo light is an em wave with oscillating electric field and magnetic field. So what creates these fields

@This isn't a discussion board. If you have another question, please post a new question. (first, search the site to make sure you can't find the question already asked and answered)

I have posted another question please answer.

@HimanshuNirwam If it is a complete new separate question, perhaps put a link to it the comments?

Light can be modeled as large numbers of massless photons traveling together through space. If we model them this way, then the reason that they can travel great distances is that they encounter very little matter in their journey which would scatter or absorb them. That is, empty space is almost completely transparent to photons.
As these photons depart from a source of light like a star, they expand outward in 3 dimensions, which dilutes their concentration (number of photons per second traveling through a square meter of surface) but does not reduce their total number. So at a very very large distance from the source, there are very very few photons per square meter zipping by- but not zero.
Similarly, if we model electromagnetic disturbances as waves, the wave amplitude falls off with distance from the source too and becomes very feeble at great distances- but again, not zero. This is true if there is no matter in the way which would reflect the waves or absorb their energy.
All these effects have the result of allowing photons of light, or EM waves, to reach the earth from all the way across the known universe via pathways that have no matter (dust, gas molecules, etc.) blocking them.

The OP is talking about a photon as a wave and an individual photon wave would presumably get spread out considerably over great distances. I think that is what he is getting at, rather than the combined properties of millions of photons.

@KDP, will edit. -NN

You are right! Light is indeed an Electromagnetic(EM) wave. But like all EM waves, light too can travel indefinitely.
We receive X-Ray and Microwaves from billions of light years away from space. Similarly, even light can travel such distances.
There are several reason why light(like all EMWs) can travel so far without degrading in quality.

Space has little to no obstruction- There is usually very little to block the path of light in space.

Light is massless- Even though this is not directlty a reason, maybe you can understand better with such an example. Suppose I throw a baseball with a certain force F, and it travels a distance X. But similarly if I throw a tennis ball with same fore F it travels a larger distance than X. You know this both intuitively and mathematically. Thus you can imagine why light particles(photons) being massless can travel extremely far.


Hope you understand by this!
